# Substitute techniques for "document.execCommand"

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, execcommand

I am currently working on a WYSIWYG web editor using only Jquery and CSS.

I was sort of annoyed by the inconsistencies of execCommand across all browsers.

Is there another technique you can achieve something similar to execCommand does. Such a detecting highlighted text and change its CSS settings?

If someone could inspire me with the right direction I really appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For applying a CSS class to a range or selection, you can use my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) library and its [CSS class applier module](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/wiki/CSSClassApplierModule) ([demo](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/cssclassapplier.html)). I'm also working on a replacement for `document.execCommand()` built on Rangy but that's in the fairly early stages at the moment ([bold demo](http://rangy.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/bold.html)).

Comment: @Dennis: Demo links added to answer.